# Handling null values when bcp .csv file export

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv

```
DECLARE @CMD varchar(4000),
        @DelCMD varchar(4000),
        @HEADERCMD varchar(4000),
        @Combine varchar(4000),
        @Path varchar(4000),
        @COLUMNS varchar(4000)

-- Set values as appropriate
SET @COLUMNS = ''
SET @Path = '\\servername\share\outputpath'

-- Set up the external commands and queries we'll use through xp_cmdshell
-- Note that they won't execute until we populate the temp tables they refer to
SET @CMD = 'bcp "select * from ##OutputTable" queryout "' + @Path + '\Temp_RawData.csv" -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -T -t , -c'
SET @HEADERCMD = 'bcp "SELECT * from ##cols" queryout "' + @Path + '\Temp_Headers.csv" -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -T -t , -c'
SET @Combine = 'copy "' + @Path + '\Temp_Headers.csv" + "' + @Path + '\Temp_RawData.csv" "' + @Path + '\MyCombinedFile.csv"'
SET @DelCMD = 'del "' + @Path + '\Temp_*.csv"'

-- Create and populate our temp table with the query results
SELECT
  * INTO ##OutputTable
FROM YourSourceTable

-- Generate a list of columns   
SELECT
  @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS + c.name + ','
FROM tempdb..syscolumns c
JOIN tempdb..sysobjects t
  ON c.id = t.id
WHERE t.name LIKE '##OutputTable%'
ORDER BY colid

SELECT
  @COLUMNS AS Cols INTO ##Cols

-- Run the two export queries - first for the header, then for the data
EXEC xp_cmdshell @HEADERCMD
EXEC xp_cmdshell @CMD

-- Combine the two files into a single file
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Combine

-- Clean up the two temp files we created
EXEC xp_cmdshell @DelCMD

-- Clean up our temp tables
DROP TABLE ##cols
DROP TABLE ##OutputTable
```

I used this script to export .csv file to my path. But however it works fine for non-null values. If the result set contains any null values the formatting  crashed . How can we handle null values in bcp. Kindly advise

Comment: "the formatting crashed" -plz clarify or provide a screenshot

Comment: Hi Anton, Crashed means whenever my result set contains any null values the format was incorrect in excel. The values are not placed under respective column.

Comment: Have you tried to use other delimiters, like tab? Can the data contain a comma? Have you considered using INSULL() for nullable columns?

Comment: Also try -q option  (quoted identifiers)

Comment: Hi Anton, I have tried ISNULL() function and it works fine. However if my result set's column is having data with comma, the format again giving problem. Like if my column Remarks contains value as completed fine,Next run at 6 PM it considers as two column and placed in excel wrongly. How can i fix this comma seperated issue?

Comment: there are a few options here. First option: You can use another field terminator, like tab, |, $, etc... but you need to make sure it is unique and is not appeared in any text.

Comment: second option: you should use text qualifier (") in excel import and QUOTENAME(<column>, CHAR(34)) in your query for all text fields